# Strange behavior of ReorderableList when itemExtent != null

Tags: flutter

I set ReorderableList itemExtent and got weird sorting indentation. How can you fix it?

[DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=0c44aabd37c20507c109b0a9bb6ed34b&null_safety=true)

[image]

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) => ReorderableListView(
      itemExtent: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 5,
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: <Widget>[
        for (int index = 0; index < _items.length; index++)
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            key: Key('$index'),
            color: Colors.blue[200 + index % 5 * 100],
            child: Center(child: Text('${_items[index]}')),
          ),
      ],
      onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {},
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `itemExtent` and give its value of `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 5` to the `Container`

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) => ReorderableListView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      children: <Widget>[
        for (int index = 0; index < _items.length; index++)
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 5,
            height: double.infinity,
            key: Key('$index'),
            color: Colors.blue[200 + index % 5 * 100],
            child: Center(child: Text('${_items[index]}')),
          ),
      ],
      onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {},
    );
```

Comment: Without `itemExtent` i have another [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69135503/flutter-scroll-snap-in-sliverlist).

Comment: do you still have the bug with newer flutter SDK ? Working all fine here with 2.5.3 (on your post 2.5.0 is used)

Comment: Updated the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69135503/flutter-scroll-snap-in-sliverlist). Bug still actual in `Flutter 2.5.3 Dart SDK 2.14.4`.